# performSelectorInBackground form another h.file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have function in `Functions.h` that I want to use from another h file.
I tried:

```
#import "Functions.h"
....
Functions *Func = [[Functions alloc]init];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(?????????) withObject:nil];
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking…In addition, it's not an Xcode question

Comment: What? Let's see code in context please. And don't use question marks  like you are, that's unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the methods are *instance methods*,

```
Functions *func = [[Functions alloc] init];
[func performSelectorInBackground:@selector(theMethodToRunInBackground) withObject:nil];
```

If they are *class methods*,

```
[Functions performSelectorInBackground:@selector(theMethodToRunInBackground) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: What about the bit about doing this from a header file?  The OP is off-track WRT that.

Comment: That's a good point. I guess the OP might actually wanted to do it from other class. May be he used a wrong phrase.

Comment: @trojanfoe EmptyStack and trojanfoe: for the sake of completeness, could one of you show how that could be done doing it from a header file? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Func` instead of `self`

```
[Func performSelectorInBackground:@selector(function) withObject:nil];
```